# Expected value and variance for Itô Integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

This is my first question and I hope it is ok :)

Reading in a book I came along this answer to a question I did not understand and I would like to understand this very much:

Problem: Calculate the mean and variance of the Itô integral $\int_0^tW_s^2dWs$ with $W_s$ being an Brownian motion.

The solution says that $I_t=\int_0^tW_s^2dW_s$, that Itô integrals are martingales and that therefore $E(I_t)=I_0=0$, I get this part. I also understand that $$Var(I_t)=E(I_t^2)=E(\int_0^tW_s^2ds)$$ by Itô isometry and that $E(W_s^4)=3s^2$ and therefore $Var(I_t)=t^3$. I do not understand that last part unfortunatly. How to we get to the variance?

Also how is it that we can get from the $E(W_s^4)$ to $E(\int_0^tW_s^2ds)$ and how did we use the facts $E(I_t)=I_0=0$ in the beginning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process $I=\{I_t: t \geq 0\}$ is a martingale and thus (check out the properties of a martingale) the expected value remains constant, i.e.,
$$\forall t \geq 0, \ \ \mathbb{E}[I_t]=\mathbb{E}[I_0]=\mathbb{E}[0]=0  $$
The variance of $I_t$ is then given by
$$Var(I_t)=\mathbb{E}[I_t^2]-\mathbb{E}[I_t]^2=\mathbb{E}[(\int_0^tW_s^2 \, ds)^2]-0=\int_0^t\mathbb{E}[W_s^4] \, ds =\int_0^t 3s^2 \, ds = t^3$$
where we used Itô's isometry which states that
$$\mathbb{E}[(\int_0^tY_s \, ds)^2]=\int_0^t\mathbb{E}[Y_s^2] \, ds$$

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: @Babado, this is not quite right. The Ito isometry tells us that $\Bbb E[I_t^2] =\Bbb E\left[\left(\int_0^t W_s^2\,dW_s\right)^2\right]=\Bbb E\left[\int_0^t W_s^4\,ds\right]=\int_0^t 3s^2\,ds$.

Comment: isn't $\mathbb{E}[\int_0^t X_s \, ds] =\int_0^t \mathbb{E}[ X_s] \, ds  $ ?